# Use the loop to check if DB record exists in WordPress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, loops

I have a somewhat unorthodox (i guess) question. I have a function that adds a record to my MYSQL DB, with location lat and lng info. However sometimes that function is not working correctly, causing for the the DB record not to be created. Therefore I would like to create a loop to keep checking if the function created the DB record and if not, do the function again.
Just to be clear; the function I use is a default GEOMyWP function ([reference](http://docs.geomywp.com/gmw_pt_update_location/#examples)). Sometimes it is not working properly, I guess due to the Google maps API response time.

I have the following in my functions.php and it seems to be working. I really would like to know if this is a proper way to accomplish the above, since I am not sure. Thanks

```
global $wpdb;
$myccount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations WHERE object_id = %d", $post_id));
    if ($myccount <= 0) :
      while ($myccount <= 0) :
         gmw_pt_update_location( $args ); //The function I would like to check.
         $myccount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations WHERE object_id = %d", $post_id));
      endwhile;
    endif;
```

Below is the function that i use to import the address, when creating a post for a CPT

```
function gmw_update_post_type_post_location(  $post_id ) {

    // Return if it's a post revision
    if ( false !== wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
        return;

    // check autosave //
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    //check if user can edit post
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
    //Add post Meta
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'address', $_POST['address'], false);

    //get the address from the custom field "address"
    $addressarray = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'address', true );
    $address = $addressarray[0];
    //$address = $_POST['address'];

    //varify that address exists. Otherwise abort the function.
    if ( empty( $address ) )
        return;

    //include the update location file file
    include_once( GMW_PT_PATH .'/includes/gmw-pt-update-location.php' );

    //make sure the file included and the function exists
    if ( !function_exists( 'gmw_pt_update_location' ) )
        return;

    //Create the array that will pass to the function
    $args = array(
            'post_id' => $post_id, //Post Id of the post 
            'address' => $address // the address we pull from the custom field above
    );
    //Start counting 1
    global $wpdb;
    $myccount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations WHERE object_id = %d", $post_id));
    if ($myccount <= 0) :
    while ($myccount <= 0) :
    //Add location
    gmw_pt_update_location( $args );

    //Start counting 2
    $myccount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gmw_locations WHERE object_id = %d", $post_id));
    endwhile;
    endif;
}
//execute the function whenever post type is being updated
add_action( 'save_post_mpp-gallery', 'gmw_update_post_type_post_location', 13, 1 );
```

Function that is inserting a record to the db is eventually: gmw_update_location
This function can be found in the GEOMyWP plugin. See this link for some reference: https://github.com/Fitoussi/geo-my-wp/blob/master/includes/gmw-location-functions.php#LC194

Comment: Add the function source code, to understand how exactly you are performing transaction inside.

Comment: Ok, added the code.

Comment: #1. First of all, as I can assume. You have a MySql function which is called by application code and passing some value to them. Now you are not sure that the function is really saving your data or not?  Sorry, but suppose to mention that, I am asking for MySQL function code. So that I can understand how function performing the transaction.

Comment: Hi, see the edit. Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question right, you should be able to customize your WP_Query with a `meta_query` nested array, using your custom field name as the `'key'` and the `'compare' => 'EXISTS' ` operator. [See more here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)

Comment: Hi, thanks. I guess i could but my `SELECT COUNT` query is doing the same atm and working. The thing is that i am not sure if this is a best practice to make sure a DB record is added. Thanks